# How to create a custom header view for a table view section using outlets and IB

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

I would like to make a custom header view for a table view section in Xamarin.IOS with interface builder. However, I dont want this view to have a static content, instead I would like to create outlets, so I can modify the element's value contained in the view.

I have done custom table view cells before with interface builder (piece of cake), so the question is: is there any way to accomplish this on a section header too?

This is what I want to do:

[image]

PD: I'm using monotouch.dialog, and this controller is a DialogViewController

Comment: create a freeform size viewcontroller in storyboard, with it's own class and outlets. instantiate it from storyboard  and use it as your table's header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use a `UIViewController` instead a `UITableViewController` and put the first part of your design (the user information and the buttons) in a `UIView` and the restrings section in a `UITableView`.

It's a better solution than implementing a `UITableViewController` with multiple headers.

let me know if it works for you.